# Excel Automatic data update

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create an inventory system using excel. For now, I have 8 sheets (othersheet), which basically contains the same format and table, but with different data or records. I would like to gather all the records from all the table from these 8 othersheets and copy it to a new sheet (mainsheet). I would also like to make it automatic, e.g. every time I add a new record into any othersheet, it would also be automatically added to my mainsheet.

I've been trying to research this for about a week now, but with no luck :/

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('mainsheet'!F$13:F$1223,SMALL(IF('mainsheet'!E$13:E$1223="SI",ROW(B$7:B$1200)-ROW(B$7)+1),ROWS(B$7:B7))),"")
```

This line of code is inserted on cell E13 of my mainsheet. For now, this only work for one othersheet. The automatic function is already working, but like I said, it does not work for all othersheets. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spreading data across several sheets and then trying to report across all sheets is always a challenge. The best way to avoid this is to use the golden rule that all data goes into ONE sheet to begin with.

If that is not an option, formulas are inferior for collating the data, because you can't know how far to copy the formula down and will waste space by pre-populating empty rows with formulas.

So, what else can you do?

I suggest you get a copy of the free [Power Query add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=39379) from Microsoft.

It is available as an add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as "Get & Transform".

Add each sheet's data table as a query (connection only), then create one main query that appends the individual sheet queries. As soon as data is added to any of the sheets, refresh the main query.

No code, no formulas.

Comment: Hello @teylyn, I've downloaded the add-in as you've suggested, however, I'm unable to install it. This [ERROR](https://postimg.org/image/s0oo5imkz/) appears every time I try to install it. Here's some info about my installed [OFFICE](https://postimg.org/image/qmx1a7nbn/). What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: is there no other way? I'm still unable to install power query :/

Comment: Yes, you need either one of the versions in the message. Why don't you just install the SP1 for Office 2010? Then Power Query will install.